# Selectively copy a Graphics2D component

Tags: java, graphics2d

is it possible to take a certain area of a graphics2D component and paint it to a different JFrame?

IE 
take  x = 0 to 200 and y = 200 to 400 from a Graphics2D component and paint that area to a different Jframe.

Comment: `Graphics2D` is only the drawing interface. The actual component is `BufferedImage` or such.

Comment: Please clarify: a Graphics2D  is not a component but more like a pen used to draw images with, so I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dstImg.getGraphics(Image srcimg, int dx1, int dy1, int dx2, int dy2, int sx1, int sy1, int sx2, int sy2, ImageObserver observer);`. These coordinates refer to top-hand (1) and bottom-hand (2) coordinates respectively, while `d` and `s` refer to destination and source (you are defining the source and destination rectangles). Use `null` for the last argument.

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) for official Javadoc.

Comment: how would i take a graphics component and turn that into an image that i could use for that particular method?

Comment: new BufferedImage(...). You can't create Images from Graphics.

Comment: You can then use createGraphics() on the Image.